# Exclude white space from Elasticsearch when searching

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5

I've got elastic search working great on my site, I can search pretty descent. My problem is when i do a search on something like HipHop vs Hip Hop, or cellphone vs cell phone, my results for the first text query won't appear . I want to make it so that if a user searches either word with or without a space, the results will be the same. here's what my code to search looks like. I'm using Laravel 5

```
 $q = $request->input('q');
  $response = $client->search([
        'index' => 'users',
        'type' => 'user',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        ['match' => [ 'text' => $q ] ],
                    ],
                ],  
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you must understand the index process, basically your string is passed trough the [default analyser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) if you didn't change the default mapping.

HipHop will kept the same

Hip Hop is saved separated like Hip, Hop

When you do a match query like your example with HipHop vs Hip Hop, this query is passed trough the analyser too and will be separated like: "HipHop, vs, Hip, Hop" and a boolean query that will do a search like this: "match HipHop there?", "match vs there?", "match Hip there?", "match Hop there?" ?

If you want a scenario where you have HipHop indexed and the user search for Hip Hop or HipHop vs Hip Hop or HopHip and should return HipHop, you must implement some strategy like:

Regex or prefix query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Ngram for partial matching: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html

Synonyms: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html

And if you want to keep you terms with space indexed like "Hip Hop" you need to use a not_analyzed mapping.

Comment: could you give me a code example, based on what I'm doing?